# Visual Studio - Reconcile TFS gated build closes all open documents, including other build statuses

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Often when I check-in my changes they go into numerous branches simultaneously through a gated build which take a few minutes (check-ins are separated by branch, which I have in different local workspace mappings). I wish to monitor them because we've had issues of random build failures (unrelated to the code being checked-in) and need to update status in our internal tracking tool once they complete.

[image]

But when I reconcile any of them (when they succeed), every open file is closed on me, including all other Build Request tabs:

[image]

**A couple questions**: Why must VS assume I want to close everything (and how to stop it), and how can I reopen *this kind* of check-in status tab manually? Opening from the Builds page of team Explorer opens a different version that horribly lags each time it refreshes.

[image]

[image]

<sub>(lag is presumably from the copious number of warning messages)</sub>

P.S. I am not checking-in solution files that would cause a reload (and opening a different solution file doesn't close open documents anyway), but this only seems to occur when I reconcile changes in the currently-opened solution.

Comment: What's your detail Visual Studio Version?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

***Update***

I could not reproduce your issue in my test environment, all tabs such as other opened build status, source control explorer, opened .cs file tab, even with the preview window which not be pinned keep opened. As below screenshot:

[image]

After build succeed, then click reconcile workspace button, a pop-up window need to choose, simply select yes or yes to all.  No tabs been closed neither.

[image]

I have also done multiple tests, under what circumstances these build status tabs will be closed in Visual Studio.

Found that even if you switch workspace/ switch project in team explorer during the process, all tabs will still keep opened.

Unless you switch a connected user, those tabs will be closed (also make sense)

[image]

Back to your issues, suggest you to give a try with Visual Studio in other computers to check if your issue still exist. This will narrow down if it related to your personal setting.

**As a workaround, you could track all of your gated build status in web portal instead of Visual Studio**.

---

As for there are different pages. You could check the detail info for your screenshot shared here. One for build status page, one for build request page.

If you want to re-open the build request summary. You could click the corresponding build request  in your build status page such as below:

[image]

Comment: I've had issues with having other pending changes in my workspace enough, to ensure the only things are what I am checking-in, so theoretically there *can't* be any conflicts to resolve (and I don't see any other windows appear).

Comment: @Elaskanator I have done some tests and analysis with my visual studio 2017, could not reproduce your issue. Please see my updates with more details. Hope it be helpful.

Comment: Next time I will generate a [PSR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/22878/windows-10-record-steps) trace. Thanks.

Comment: The Request Summary section is not visible while it is building.

Comment: @Elaskanator There should be a prompting message when the gated build triggered . " Your check-in has been queued for validation. Click here to see the status of the validation build. "  Click the "here" will auto jump to Request Summary page. Kindly check my update screenshot for reference.

Comment: I suspect that my sqlproj getting reloaded is causing the tabs to close.
Also, if you'd look at my post, that ("Click here to see the status of the validation build") is already shown in my very first screenshot.